# Standard button on custom object on salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have installed Docusign in salesforce. The button in opportunity works but my custom button on a custom object doesn't work.

My button is standard

```
:{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} DocuSign_CreateEnvelope();
```

I have the error:

> A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was
>   encountered:
>
> ```
> unterminated string literal
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the ':' thus resulting in

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} DocuSign_CreateEnvelope();